# How can I access to this XML field?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, linq-to-xml, deserialization

I want to extract the field `yt:username` from [this](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/djfonplaz/subscriptions?v=2) XML:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(requestedURL);
var m_oListaMeteo = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "entry").Select(n =>
{
    return new
    {
        username = n.Element(ns + "yt:username").Value
    };
});
```

but `XDocument` itself says `The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.`

A string replace is needed? Or need I to manage namespace of youtube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yt` is namespace, Try this:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/djfonplaz/subscriptions?v=2");
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
var yt = XNamespace.Get("http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007");
var m_oListaMeteo = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "entry").Select(n =>
{
    return new
    {
        username = n.Element(yt + "username").Value
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the proper namespaces:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(requestedURL);
var m_oListaMeteo = xDoc
    .Root
    .Elements("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry")
    .Select(entry => new
    {
        username = entry.Element("{http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007}username").Value
    });
```